# Using HttpPost to get data from local server

Tags: android

I used following code in java class of android. Everything works except it wont send any request. Answer is always null.

```
    public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText et; Editable ur;
TextView tx;HttpResponse response;String x;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(send);

}
private OnClickListener send = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    ur=et.getText();
      postData();
     tx.setText("ans:"+x);

    }};

public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/name.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", ur.toString()));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
       response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());
       x= EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}  }
```

and in php i used following code

```
     <?php
     $name=$_POST["name"];
      echo $name;
     ?>
```

Any idea how it make it work?

Comment: do you have the server on the device or on your computer?

Comment: yes i do.. i'm using IIS 7 with php enabled.. All other php apps work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use IP address 10.0.2.2 for localhost on the emulator.

Comment: philip: how will it  transfer data to IIS?